# Copy PDF pages in a file

Tags: vba, pdf, acrobat

I don't know how to write the VBA code to copy pages in the same PDF file.

The following code is wrong:

```
 Private Sub CommandButton17_Click()
 'Copy pages of the opened PDF file, after page x
 Dim watermarkfile As String
 Dim pdDoc As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
 Dim pdPage As Acrobat.AcroPDPage
 filenmame = "D:\\test.PDF"
 Set pdDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
 pdDoc.Open (filenmame)
 Set jso = pdDoc.GetJSObject

        Call pdDoc.CopyPagesTo(5, 5, filenmame, 1)  'Copy page 6 of the opened PDF file, after page 1
    pdDoc.Close

 End Sub
```

I googled for a long time, but I didn't find a way, thank you very much!

The pages of the PDF file before and after running the VBA code are as follows

The original PDF file pages is:1,2,3,4,5;

The pages looks like this after running the VBA code:1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
'PDF duplicate  11,22,33,44,55......
Dim pdfFolder As String
Dim sPDdoc As New Acrobat.AcroPDDoc, tPDdoc As New Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
Dim pagenum As Long, page_num As Long, I As Long, II As Long
Dim PDFfile As String, DD As String, AA As String
Dim pdDoc As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc

    pdfFolder = Sheet1.Range("A" & 2) 'file address and name
    tPDdoc.Create
    
    If sPDdoc.Open(pdfFolder) Then   'OPEN the file
        pagenum = sPDdoc.GetNumPages 'pages num
        tPDdoc.InsertPages tPDdoc.GetNumPages - 1, sPDdoc, 0, pagenum, 0 ' Create one  PDF file copy
        pagenum = sPDdoc.GetNumPages 'pages num
        tPDdoc.InsertPages tPDdoc.GetNumPages - 1, sPDdoc, 0, pagenum, 0 ',Copy the same PDF file once
    End If
    
    AA = Mid(pdfFolder, InStrRev(pdfFolder, "\") + 1, Len(pdfFolder) - InStrRev(pdfFolder, "\") - 4)  'Get the original file name, excluding the extension
    DD = Left(pdfFolder, InStrRev(pdfFolder, "\")) 'Get the original file address
    tPDdoc.Save PDSaveFull, DD & AA & "-Duplicate.PDF" 'Save Duplicate PDF file
    tPDdoc.Close 
    Set sPDdoc = Nothing
    Set tPDdoc = Nothing

'-----------------------------------------------------------------
'Sort the PDF file 11,22,33,44,55.....
    Set pdDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    PDFfile = DD & AA & "-Duplicate.PDF" 'MovePage the FILE name
    
    If pdDoc.Open(PDFfile) Then     'open file
        pagenum = pdDoc.GetNumPages / 2 'PAGES,Second half
        Set jso = pdDoc.GetJSObject
        page_num = 0 'The location to which the page will be moved    
        I = 1 '0.2.4.6.8.10....counter
            For II = pagenum + 1 To pagenum * 2 'Second half Begin
                page_num = 2 * (I - 1)
                Call jso.MovePage(II - 1, page_num) 'Call MovePage functions
                I = I + 1
            Next
    End If
    
    pdDoc.Save 1, watermarkfile 'Save the file, duplicate name overwrite is not prompted
    pdDoc.Close
    Set pdDoc = Nothing
    MsgBox "OK"
End Sub
```